# Navbar with search box - MaterializeCss

Tags: css, asp.net, frontend, materialize, web-frontend

I'm trying to create a functional search bar inside my nav bar with materializecss. I can put the search icon and write text inside it but it doesn't work. I only have the design part. I'm not being able to find the jquery to initialize the search box and make it work.

```
<ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
                        <li>
                            <div class="input-field col s6 s12 white-text">
                                <i class="white-text small material-icons prefix">search</i>
                                <input type="text" placeholder="search" id="autocomplete-input" class="white-text">
                            </div>
                        </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not initialized autocomplete and it's options in JS file.
You can check JS code below.

Try to run the demo below, a search bar with implemented autocomplete.
 You can get **Apple, Microsoft and Google** in the search bar autocomplete.
For more options add them in the data object under autocomplete initialization.

```js
var myData={
      "Apple": null,
      "Microsoft": null,
      "Google": 'https://placehold.it/250x250'
    };

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({
    data: myData,
    limit: 20, // The max amount of results that can be shown at once. Default: Infinity.
    onAutocomplete: function(val) {
      // Callback function when value is autcompleted.
    },
    minLength: 1, // The minimum length of the input for the autocomplete to start. Default: 1.
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>



<div class="row">
  <div class="col s12">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="input-field col s12">
        <i class="material-icons prefix">search</i>
        <input type="text" id="autocomplete-input" class="autocomplete">
        <label for="autocomplete-input">Search</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi,

Sorry for the delay in answering, is there any chance to add the objects dinamically to the autocomplete as they are added to the database?

Comment: just pass your object to data

Comment: How is the syntaxis for that?

Comment: Check the demo above, I have updated it , check myData object

Comment: @pedro-lopez If you find it helpful then please vote up and mark it as answer